# jquery animate function overlapping footer

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm currently working on a website and one of the page contains a jQuery animate function that moves a `div` container as I scroll along the page. This works fine however when I zoom in or make the screen bigger it overlaps with the footer.

How can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/css.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/js.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

//Larger thumbnail preview 

$("#thumbImages.thumb p").hover(function() {



    $(this).css({'z-index' : '10'});
    $(this).find('img').addClass("hover").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '-110px', 
            marginLeft: '-110px', 
            top: '50%', 
            left: '50%', 
            width: '170px', 
            height: '170px',
            padding: '20px' 
        }, 200);

    } , function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
    $(this).find('img').removeClass("hover").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '0', 
            marginLeft: '0',
            top: '0', 
            left: '0', 
            width: '100px', 
            height: '100px', 
            padding: '5px'
        }, 400);
});

//Swap Image on Click
    $("#thumbImages.thumb p a").click(function() {

        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="imageLoad">LOADING...</span>');  
        $('#imageLoad').fadeIn('normal'); 


        var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); //Find Image Name
        $("#main_view img").attr({ src: mainImage }, hideLoader());
        return false;       



    function hideLoader() {  
        $('#imageLoad').fadeOut('normal');  
    }
    });

});
</script>

<script>
    $().ready(function() {
        var $main_view = $("#main_view");

        $(window).scroll(function(){            
            $main_view
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() - 14) + "px" }, "slow" );

        });
    });


</script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">

  <h1>Header</h1>
     <ul>
        <li id="nav1"><a href="../index.html">Welcome</a></li>
        <li id="nav1"><a href="about.html">Why Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a></li>
        <li id="nav1"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li id="nav1"><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="other.html"> Other </a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="7RepairSteps.html"> Repair Steps</a></li>
        <li><a href="scaletrix.html">Scaletrix</a></li>
        <li><a href="reviews.html">Customer Reviews</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="nav1"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content">

    <div id="portfolioImages" style="height:900px;">
    <h2>Our Work</h2>

    <div class="thumb" id="thumbImages">
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/before1.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/before1.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/before1i.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/before1i.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/after1.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/after1.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/after1i.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/after1i.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/before2.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/before2.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/after2.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/after2.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/before3.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/before3.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/after3.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/after3.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/before4.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/before4.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/after4.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/after4.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/before5.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/before5.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/before5i.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/before5i.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/after5.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/after5.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    <p style="z-index: 0;"><a href="../images/portfolio/after5i.jpg"><img  class="" src="../images/portfolio/after5i.jpg" alt=""></a></p>
    </div>

    <div style="border:solid; width:410px; overflow:hidden; float:right"" id="main_view"><a href="" title="" target=""><img src="../images/portfolio/before1.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>

    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="foot" style="position:relative;"> Footer Information </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#content a:link {color:#686868; text-decoration:none;}
#content a:visited {color: #686868; text-decoration:none;}
#content a:hover {color: #686868; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;}
#content a:active {color: #686868; text-decoration:none;}
#content a:focus{color: #686868; text-decoration:none;}

body {
    font: 0.8em "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #343434;
    background: #7DC623;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;


}
#wrapper {
    width: 710px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #0d0d0d url(../images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
    padding: 55px 25px 25px 25px;
    border: 12px solid #2e2e2e;
    position:relative;
}
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.3em 0;
    text-indent:-99999px;
}


    ul {

    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
    background: #2e2e2e url(../images/nav_bar.jpg) repeat-x;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    height:33px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    text-align: center;
    }
    ul li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
    li ul {
        display: none;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    ul li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #49BDEF;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin-top: 0;
        text-align: center;


    }

    input{
        color: #49BDEF;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin-top: 0;
        background: #2e2e2e url(../images/nav_bar.jpg) repeat-x;
    }


    li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    li:hover li {
        float: none;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    li:hover a { background: #1b1b1b url(../images/nav_bar_o.jpg) repeat-x;}

    li:hover li a:hover {
        background: #1e7c9a;
    }

#load {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    background: url(../images/ajax-loader.gif);
    width: 43px;
    height: 11px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#imageLoad {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    background: url(../images/loader.gif);
    width: 43px;
    height: 11px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#content {
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    color:#568945;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em 0;
    color:#686868;
    line-height:1.4em;
}
#content img.right {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 8px 8px;

}

#content img.left {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 8px 2px 4px;

}

#productImage{
width: 193px; 
height:145px
}

#productImage:hover{
    width: 250px;
    height:200px;
}

#sampleImage{
    width: 193px; 
    height:145px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#sampleImage:hover{
    width: 250px;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#foot {
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    border-top:1px solid #222222;
}



#searchbox
{

    height: 30px;

    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #0d0d0d;

}

#searchbox:hover
{

    height: 100%;

    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #0d0d0d;
}


#content {
}

#thumbImages.thumb {
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 10px;
    width: 260px;
}
#thumbImages.thumb p {
    margin: 0; padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 110px;
    float:left;
    height: 110px;

}
#thumbImages.thumb p img {
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; 
}
#thumbImages.thumb p img.hover {
    background:none;
    border: none;
}

#main_view img {
    height: 310px;
    width: 410px;
    border: none;

}
```

Comment: you can use http://jsfiddle.net for demo

Comment: Does this solve . http://jsfiddle.net/cr8L9/   ...?

Comment: YES OMG! Thank you so much!! I just had to change $('body').height() - 500 to $('#wrapper').height() - 500....thanks alot A.V